# cannot start appium test: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Description:
Here below code of simple AppiumDriver initialization which always fails
with error below (independently whether selenium is present in maven dependencies or not)

test:

```
@Test
    public void testSomething() throws MalformedURLException {
        AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), new DesiredCapabilities());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

https://www.refheap.com/d0ec095c62d8061ac2cef768d

output error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at                   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
```

https://www.refheap.com/b71dbf880e1c997b3a885c13d

POM.XML:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

       //Here was 2 cases: with and without selenium dependency
       //both was not helpful
```

Interesting: 
If I create simple Selenide\selenium test without appium in the same project where mentioned test is located - all tests are correctly working

What I did:
maven .m2 folder clean up - did not help,
importing\deleting selenium java clients - did not help,
Creating clean project  - did not help,

does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see that appium java-client already contains a dependency on selenium selenium-java 2.47.1 inside it's pom file (https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/pom.xml).

NoClassDefFoundError might be thrown when there is a conflict between the same classes in a jar.

I would suggest you to delete

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

from your pom and try to run it. I hope it helps.

Comment: I mentioned in header: @independently@ whether selenium is present in maven dependencies or not.

Comment: I used to run it with selenium\ without selenium I used to run it with all common sense dependency combinations.. lowering the versions....etc ... the fact is I have this code is working on other laptop...and does not work here...that is why ia am here...it is not somethig common

Answer (score 0):

```
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>

    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>

    <version>2.47.1</version>

</dependency>
```

use this in your pom.xml